# Launch .apk File

Tags: android-studio, apk

I have a `.apk` file, and I want to launch it on `Android Studio`. So when I searched online and found one solution, when I open that file through `Android Studio`, I get

[image: this]

so here where I get stuck, when I hit the run button I get

[image: this]

---

*What are the steps to launch apk file ?*

Comment: Are you trying to see it's code or you just want to run and see that that `.apk` file does ?

Comment: im trying to see the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 1):

APK is compiled, ready to launch app. What you need, is open is through real device, or emulator:

1) copy file to your device, find it by file manager, install it and run like every other app

2) run emulator, drag and drop *.apk file into it, it will install it, then just run app

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use online `.apk` *code extractor tools* like [this](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) to achieve that you are looking for.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/6390175) for further details